# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement evaluate

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, opensuse

[Here](https://pypi.org/project/evaluate/) they say the `Evaluate` library has to be installed in a virtual environment. So I follow [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) and I create and activate a virtual environment doing:

```
python3 -m venv env
```

and

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Then when I try to install the evaluate package

```
python3 -m pip install requests
```

This happens:

```
(env) bscuser@localhost:~> python3 -m pip install evaluate
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement evaluate (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for evaluate
```

How can I solve this?

I'm using OpenSuse Leap 15.3 and my Python version is 3.6.15.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the left side-bar on PyPi package page for [`evaluate`](https://pypi.org/project/evaluate/).  Near the bottom is the "Programming Language" section.  It lists availability for Python version 3.7 to 3.10.

You will need to create a new environment with one of those versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error even for python 3.7:

```
user@dot:~/PycharmProjects/tsg$ python --version
Python 3.7.16
user@dot:~/PycharmProjects/tsg$ pip3 install evaluate
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement evaluate
ERROR: No matching distribution found for evaluate
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.0.1; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

... but after upgrading `pip` It was resolved:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```